# PHP include file as an absolute path - is this correct?

Tags: php

I have several instances of php includes on some of my pages (usual things like footer markup and headers etc) and Id rather use an absolute php path rather than the ../../ relative path I am using.

I thought this would work:

```
<?php include
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/dir/script_name.php");
?>
```

- my question is: is the /dir/script_name.php - the exact full path, and if so, what is the point of `__FILE__ ?`

The function dirname() removes the file name from the path and gives us the absolute path of the directory the file is in - right? So why bother with the function dirname() if I am already giving the full path - ?

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`__FILE__` is the php [magic variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) which is the full path of the currently executing file (where it appears), `dirname()` removes the file name from it, thereby giving you the full path of the folder the current script is in.

It is really just a hack, as another magic variable `__DIR__` (the directory of the currently executing script) was only added in 5.3 and therefore the `dirname(__FILE__)` was the easiest way to achieve the same thing in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

> The function dirname() removes the file name from the path and gives us the absolute path of the directory the file is in - right?

Yes, this is correct. The path you can use could be relative or the full system path.

> So why bother with the function dirname() if I am already giving the full path - ?

If you are hard coding the full file system path then your application will become less portable; Your webroot directory would be different from mine. This is normally why you will see code with the path being generated like this.

I would personally look into the [PHP autoloader](http://php.net/autoload) as a much more flexible alternative to managing class includes.

Comment: ok...thanks, so, am I correct in thinking that there is a single .php file that contains the full path and I would refer to that one fine - sort of like a .css and styles sheet?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what you mean by "a single .php file that contains the full path"?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want. In the strictest sense, the path you're describing is "relative" to the file you're executing. For a true absolute path, just make sure the filename starts with a "/".
like so:

```
include "/path/to/file/script.php";
```